# Typing in React Native - "Binding element 'navigation' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)"

Tags: node.js, react-native, navigation, expo, stack-navigator

not new to programming but new to app development and reactive native. I have been searching for almost four hours to solve this. I have realised there are many questions like this, but this is not a duplicate as any working code has not worked on mine.

I followed [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigation) tutorial and VS code gave me errors. Namely, relating to Text and Button imports in the .tsx screen file. The following code is constantly giving me an error:

```
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    return (
      <Button
        title="Go to Jane's profile"
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate('Profile', { name: 'Jane' })
        }
     />
   );
};
```

The error: Binding element 'navigation' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)

From what I gather this is related to typing in the language and because the type has not been declared, I cannot use the code. The problem is, is that I have followed the tutorial, searched many different websites and a few different tutorials, I have not been able to get this working.

I have tried all of these variations for the first line:

```
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation.navigate ) => {
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation } : Navigator) => {
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation NavigationContainer}) => {
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation = NavigationAction}) => {
const HomeScreen = ({ }) => {
```

So I have tried quite a few different variations to try to solve this. I am honestly really stuck, after trying to follow the tutorial and finding no answers online, I really do not know what to do. I am sure there is something very obvious wrong with the syntax but being new to the language I don't know how to spot it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

```
import { StackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/stack';

...

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }:StackScreenProps<{Profile: any}>) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a type for navigation.

```
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation:: StackNavigationProp<HomeParamList> }) => {}
```

So in `HomeParamList` you can define the navigation paths.

```
export type HomeParamList= {
    Home: undefined;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however when I use this code it says has three errors - one after the second colo where it says "expression expected",  the second under the } where it says " '(' expected" and the third under the => where it says " ';' expected" ... i am not sure what this means?